# Multiple Buttons In One Method Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

These are my buttons and I want to change the text of my statusbar as the mouse entered a certain button. I want to use only one method for mouse entering a button. How to do that?

```
self.connectBtn = tk.Button(self.master, text="CONNECT", width=8)
self.connectBtn.place(x=10, y=100)

self.backupBtn = tk.Button(self.master, text="BACKUP", width=8)
self.backupBtn.place(x=80, y=100)

self.copyBtn = tk.Button(self.master, text="COPY", width=8)
self.copyBtn.place(x=10, y=130)

self.moveBtn = tk.Button(self.master, text="MOVE", width=8)
self.moveBtn.place(x=80, y=130)

for self.button in [self.connectBtn, self.backupBtn, self.copyBtn, self.moveBtn]:
    self.button.bind("<Enter>", self.mouseOver)
    self.button.bind("<Leave>", self.mouseLeave)
```

My method for mouseOver

```
def mouseOver(self, *args):
    if self.backupBtn:
        self.status['text'] = "Backups the selected database."
    elif self.connectBtn:
        self.status['text'] = "Copies the selected database."
    elif self.button == self.moveBtn:
        self.status['text'] = "Moves the selected database."
```

If mouse entered the button for Backup then the text in statusbar should be "Backups the selected database." then on the rest of other button. I don't know what to use for if else for those buttons. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SO [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) recommends posting a minimal, complete, verifiable example (which too few people do ;-).  I recommend experimenting with the same.  When run from Idle or the console (to have a place to print to), the following prints 'Success!' every time the mouse enters the button.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
but = tk.Button(root, text = 'Hi')
but.pack()
print(but)
def cb(event):
    if event.widget == but:
        print('Success!')
but.bind('<Enter>', cb)
root.mainloop()
```

The key points are: callbacks get one argument, an event object; events have about 20 attributes, one being the widget; widgets can be compared for equality.  Applied to your code, the following would (should) work.

```
def mouseOver(self, event):
    if event.widget == self.backupBtn:
        self.status['text'] = "Backs up the selected database."
    elif event.widget == self.connectBtn:
        self.status['text'] = "Connects to the selected database."
    ...
```

However, I personally would factor the code further.

```
action = {self.backupBtn: 'Backs up', self.connectBtn: 'Connects to',
    self.moveBtn: 'Copies', self.moveBtn: 'Moves'}
def mouseOver(self, event):
    self.status['text'] = "%s the selected database." % action[event.widget]
```

Comment: thanks for a precise answer ;) i will also follow your advice too :) thank you again!

Comment: Great.  I actually answered this by experimenting with multiple versions of` `cb`.  `def cb(*args): print(args)` verified that bind callbacks get exactly one arg.  `def cb(event): print(dir(event))` showed that there was an attribute `.widget`.  `def cb(event): print(event.widget == but)` showed that it was comparable to and equal to the Button return object.  I could have looked all this up somewhere, but seeing it in actions works better for me.  This sort of small-step minimal-code experimentation should be taught in programming classes better than it seems to be.